# .then(result) block not executing after paytm payment successful. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, payment, paytm

I am integrating **paytm** transaction in react native app. and I have successfully integrated it. I am able to do successful transaction. but after transaction successful. some data from server API is showing over there. like this =
`"[{"message":"success","is_payment_done":"Y"}]"`.

But the problem is `.then(result)` block is not executing. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
export default class payment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order_id: "",
      mid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      tranxToken: "",
      amount: "20",
      // callbackUrl:
      //   "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=TESTORDER_1",
      isStaging: true,
      appInvokeRestricted: true,
    };
  }

  call_api = () => {
    fetch("https://xxxxxxx.in/App_API_CI/xxxxxxxxxx", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify([
        {
          mobile_no: "xxxxxxxxx",
          user_id: "xx",
          patient_name: "xxxxxxx",
        },
      ]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())

      .then((response) => {
        console.log(
          "this checksum api esponse" +
            JSON.stringify(response[0].data.txnToken)
        );

        this.setState({ order_id: response[0].data.order_id });
        this.setState({ tranxToken: response[0].data.txnToken });

        this.handleTransaction();
      });
  };

  handleTransaction = () => {
    AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
      this.state.order_id,
      this.state.mid,
      this.state.tranxToken,
      this.state.amount,
      "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=" +
        this.state.order_id,
      this.state.isStaging,
      this.state.appInvokeRestricted
    )

      .then((result) => {
        () => console.log(result);
        //AsyncStorage.setItem("is_payment_done", "Y");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawerRP");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        Toast.show("Something went wrong");
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.call_api}
          style={{
            height: 90,
            width: width / 1.2,
            backgroundColor: "#7DF8F8",
            justifyContent: "center",
            elevation: 20,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontSize: 35, color: "#000080" }}>
            PAY 20/-
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `.then(result)` block, I can see an arrow function declaration with `console.log` inside it, you can put `console.log` outside of the arrow function may be to check the result.

Comment: yes I have try this but didnt work

Comment: Well, I recommend using `async/await`. It will help you debug the code in synchronous manner

Answer (score 1):

For some async activity like getting data from server (the server take a little time to return data ) it's necessary  to use async/await to not fail the returned data
For  your code try it like this :

```
call_api =  async () => {
await fetch("https://xxxxxxx.in/App_API_CI/xxxxxxxxxx", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },

    body: JSON.stringify([
        {
            mobile_no: "xxxxxxxxx",
            user_id: "xx",
            patient_name: "xxxxxxx",
        },
    ]),
})
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())

    .then((response) => {
        console.log(
            "this checksum api esponse" +
            JSON.stringify(response[0].data.txnToken)
        );

        this.setState({ order_id: response[0].data.order_id });
        this.setState({ tranxToken: response[0].data.txnToken });

        this.handleTransaction();
    });
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to have few checks here

1. Check whats the result printed for below code before calling handleTransaction

   ```
   console.log(
      "this checksum api esponse" +
        JSON.stringify(response[0].data.txnToken)
    );
   ```
2. Check if the handleTransaction block is called
3. () => this wont execute console.log(result) and print the log , remove this  from below code

   ```
   .then((result) => {
    ()=> //remove this 
     console.log("result", result)
    })
   ```
4. If the handleTransaction is executed there might be some issue in startTransaction block, debug and check or wrap the code inside handleTransaction in try catch

For the 4th step asked, place the below code and check the logs

```
 handleTransaction = () => {
 console.log("handleTransaction Called")
 try{
 AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
 this.state.order_id,
 this.state.mid,
 this.state.tranxToken,
 this.state.amount,
"https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=" +
 this.state.order_id,
 this.state.isStaging,
 this.state.appInvokeRestricted
 )
.then((result) => {
  console.log("startTransaction Result ",result);
  this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawerRP");
 })
 .catch((err) => {
  console.log("startTransaction error", err)
 });
 } catch (error) {
 console.log("handleTransaction error", error)
  }
  }
```

Comment: how to do 4 th step please help

Comment: sorry 4 th step also not make any difference. I think  problem is with callbackURL. bcoz when I remove calllbackURL then .then(result) block works. But by removing callbackURL I am not able to do transaction of paymentis.

Comment: What does it display in your console? Did you find anything displaying in your console? Whats the last thing displayed in your console after this "checksum api esponse"

Comment: To get a clear picture about the actual issue you can attach here a screenshot of your console